# count max records in web service

Tags: vb.net

I want to count max records called srno from table called complaint in a database. How to write it in web service?

I am using this code 
        'open

```
    Dim cmd18 As OleDbCommand
    Try
        'MsgBox("open")
        cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CRM.mdb")
        cnn.Open()
        msg = "select count(srno) from [Complaint] where [status]= '" & Me.RadButton6.Text & "'"
        cmd18 = New OleDbCommand(msg, cnn)
        str = cmd18.ExecuteScalar()


    Catch ex As Exception
        ' MsgBox("No Records Inserted" + ex.ToString())

    Finally
        cnn.Close()


    End Try

    If str Is DBNull.Value Then
        Button1.Text = "0"
    Else
        Button1.Text = Format(CStr(TextBox1.Text)) & Convert.ToInt32(str)

    End If
```

i want in webservice..

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place where you can request users to write chunks of code for you. Feel free to have an attempt at making the web service yourself first, and then come back here with a specific issue if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You will find all your answers here http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Well then there you go!

Comment: plz help me in webservice

Comment: can u help me in only database connection in web service